# How to write test strongloop loopback

Tags: testing, loopback

I wrote api by loopback, now I want to integrate the tests in our continuous integration. So what is the tool that you use to write the tests api loopback ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the following tools:

[Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) - Test Framework

[Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) - Supertest

[Chai](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/) - Assert Library

I've made a demo project using this tools with express: You can check it [here](https://github.com/nielsenmg/xy-inc/blob/master/api/tests/poi.test.js).

Comment: I would also consider [ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) for APIs to run tests concurrently.